# How to create a bounded scrollable TabBarView

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I need to implement the following layout in Flutter.

[image: Layout]

When the user scrolls, I want the entire layout to scroll (hiding the header and tab bar). However, I can't nest a TabBarView inside a ListView since the TabBarView doesn't have a bounded height and ListViews don't provide a bounded height to their children.

I've already seen these questions, but all of them have unsatisfactory answers for this use case:

- [How can I have a TabView with variable height content within a Scrollable View with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943551/how-can-i-have-a-tabview-with-variable-height-content-within-a-scrollable-view-w?rq=1) : Exactly what I needed, but the only answer doesn't provide any concrete code on how to implement this, only a reference to a feature (SliverList) that I can't figure out how to implement.
- [how to implement a sliverAppBar with a tabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741732/how-to-implement-a-sliverappbar-with-a-tabbar) : The provided code doesn't work since the SliverList doesn't accept a constructor with this shape (and I tried adapting it to use a delegate without success).
- [Getting 'Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.' with TabBarView in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023610/getting-horizontal-viewport-was-given-unbounded-height-with-tabbarview-in-flu) : This use case doesn't work for me since I need the entire layout to scroll, and in that answer, the header is fixed to the top.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

```
class SliverWithTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SliverWithTabBarState createState() => _SliverWithTabBarState();
}

class _SliverWithTabBarState extends State<SliverWithTabBar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: false,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                background: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 200.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: FlutterLogo(),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Business Office',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Open now\nStreet Address, 299\nCity, State',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.share),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              expandedHeight: 380.0,
              bottom: TabBar(
                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'POSTS'),
                  Tab(text: 'DETAILS'),
                  Tab(text: 'FOLLOWERS'),
                ],
                controller: controller,
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.green,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100.0,
                child: Text(
                  'Flutter is awesome',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You should look for `Sliver` widgets to achieve `NestedScrollView`.

That gives you a **headerSliverBuilder** property where you can actually fit some headers that you might hide or pin on the top of the screen when the body widget is scrolled, in this particular example, a `ListView`.

You might want to take a look to the [RenderSliver](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderSliver-class.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I was finding a bit hard to wrap my head around slivers, but your example made it much clearer to me. I wish the docs had examples like these!

Comment: Thank you bro. but I can't do the scrolling tab? i have set isScrollable: true

Comment: How to swipe the widget from left to right or vice versa?

Comment: For TabBar's Tabs to work perfect,...use TabBarView in NestedScrollView's body....

Comment: This is actually not right IMO! You've put a ListView in the body of NestedScrollView. The TabBar in the header section is useless until you have a TabBarView.
But: if you put the TabBarView as the body  -> You will run into these problems:
TabBarView needs a bounded height! (It doesn't automatically take up the remaining space, and you even can't use an Extended widget to extend the height in a column).
Each Tab content has different length (in height) so you can't choose a specific height even.

Answer (score 4):

On top of Miguel Ruvio's answer replacing the ListView in the body with the TabBarView gets you almost all of the way per D.R.'s comment. I did get some overflow issues when one of my widgets in the was wrapped in a column. Replacing that with ListView per this
[example](https://codepen.io/Bryanx/pen/zYvBymX)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Tabs()));
}

class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RoomTabsState createState() => _RoomTabsState();
}

class _RoomTabsState extends State<Tabs> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _scrollViewController;
  var _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollViewController = ScrollController();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollViewController,
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, bool) => [
        SliverAppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: "All"),
              Tab(text: "Living room"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          ListView(children: [
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
            Text("test"),
          ]),
          Text("test"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

comming from this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37693#issuecomment-616140400).

Comment: It worked. Wrapping each child in `ListView` removes overflows.

Comment: Great answer! It works wrapping the children of the Tabview in a Listview. 

Note: Your Columns and Rows in the Listview should be set to MainAxisSize.min.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code below:

```
     NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
        return [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Header()
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _controller,
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.x)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.y)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.z)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
    body: Container(
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          page1(),
          page2(),
          page3(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: It makes overflows on Debug run :(