# TabBarView expanded till bottom irrespective of the start

Tags: flutter, tabbar, dynamic-resizing

I have been working on flutter, and now have to make the **Tab Bar** for the page. Since I've succeeded in making the tabs, but there is one thing which is not letting me complete my task which is this,

**I have a design blueprint which is like this:**

```
Column{
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
   children: <widget>[
      Text("Hello World!"),
      Container(child: TabWidget())
   ]
}
```

I have not given any specific height to the container of the `TabWidget()` since I wanted the Tabs to take up the full height till the bottom.

**TabWidget**

```
child: TabBar(
   controller: _controller,
   tabs: [
      new Tab(
         child: Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
           child: Text(""),
         )
      ),
      new Tab(
         child: Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
           child: Text(""),
         )
      ),    
    ]
    )
),
Container(
  //Deifining the height here, not deifing it will hide the content of the tabs
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.3,
  child: new TabBarView(
     controller: _controller,
     children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          child: Listview(
            scrollDirection: Axis.Vertical,
            children: <Widget> [
               ...
            ]
          )
        ),
        new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          child: Listview(
            scrollDirection: Axis.Vertical,
            children: <Widget> [
               ...
            ]
          )
        )  
      ]
    )
  )
  ]
);
```

Here is the catch, now I have tried my level best to get the result and hence did this :

1. Use of `Expanded()` in the TabWidget to take up the height
2. Use of `double.infinity()` in the height element of `TabBarView`
3. I have read this answer : [TabBarView without bounded height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747149/tabbarview-without-bounded-height), but I don't want my screen to scrollable, `Silver` is not required in this case. Just the **TabBarView should be expanded till the bottom irrespective of from where it is starting**

I don't want to give a particular height to my TabBarView, instead, I want it to take the full height till the bottom irrespective of the screen, so my **height is dynamic as per the screen**.

I'd like to get some inputs on this so that I'd achieve my point. I'm using `ListView()` in the child of `TabBarView`, so even if the portion size is small of the screen of the phone user will still be able to scroll the content. But the height should be till bottom, doesn't matter what the screen's size. Thanks.

Any queries are welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate the height of other widgets in the screen above the tabBar then using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` you will get the height of the screen. Deduct the remaining height from the screen height and you can use the resulting value.

P.S. Be careful with the calculations and deduct every height value other than the tab including the safe area one that you will get from `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` & `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom`.