# Flutter Not able to achieve PageView like Swipeable Tabs inside Parent ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: Reference of the Problem]

This is a Flutter Specific Query.

1. I Want to achieve the Layout Referenced in the Image above. Two Tabs
   Below a Container.
2. The Tabs can be switched using Swipe Animation    like that in a
   Page View.
3. The Tabs Contain Dynamically Generated    Widgets from Provider.
4. The Entire Page along with the Fixed Container    must be
   Scroll-able.
5. When Switching between the Tabs the fixed    container should stay
   in place and only tab Content(Column of    Widgets) should swipe
   left and right.

   What I've Tried :

   1. Using a Parent List View and Nesting the Fixed Container Child
      and Using Tab Bar to switch the Widget using Animated Switcher and
      Slide Animation. Here the Problem is i cannot swipe left and right
      and create the Page View like Effect. I also tried Nesting Page-View
      inside List-View but since the Page-View does not have a fixed height 
      ( because the tab contents are dynamically generated ).
   2. A few many more concepts i tried to tackle but the issue every time was 
      that the tab contents are not having a fixed height.

I really want to achieve this Layout and i want to know if there's any way.

Comment: This answer looks pretty much like your layout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747149/how-to-create-a-bounded-scrollable-tabbarview

Comment: @ZeRj You absolutely Pointed me to the Right Direction , Thank You!

Comment: @ZeRj But there's one more issue here, i.e the Expanded Height Property in FlexibleSpace does not contain Dynamic Height because of which The top widget cannot flexibly increase or decrease in height! Is there any way to do ?