# Flutter - dynamic height on a tab

Tags: android, layout, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a tab in the middle of a page, the tab is inside a listView, to render the the tab I had to set a fixed height on it, but the problem is that the content of the tab it will vary, it can have 1 or more items, how can I make the tab height dynamic?

Comment: use `LayoutBuilder` widget

Comment: I tried the LayoutBuilder, but it did'nt solve the problem

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem, I have a TabView inside a list view. Both tabs should contain lists of the data of variable length. Can you be more specific on how to use LayoutBuilder to achive that?

Answer (score 3):

I've answered at in the similar question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57558695/5541523

Maybe it could help you.
P.s. You will need to add GestureDetector if you want to change tabs on swipe.

[image]